# EXTJS Fileupload does not show together with dataview inside a panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I was wondering if what is wrong with the way I setup my Panel. Together with a dataview I wanted to include a fileupload with it but it seems that it doesn't show in the panel itself (only the dataview). Any way on how to do this or how to correct it? Appreciate the help.\

```
var iPanel= new Ext.panel.Panel({                                    
                                width: 490,
                                height: 500,
                                layout: 'fit',
                                title: 'Select an avatar',
                                floating: true,
                                closable : true,
                                items: {
                                    extend: 'Ext.view.View',
                                    xtype: 'dataview',
                                    id: 'myDataView',
                                    autoHeight:true,
                                    reference: 'dataview',
                                    itemSelector: 'div.dataview-multisort-item',
                                    store: Ext.create('Admin.store.users.UsersAvatarStore'),
                                    tpl: [
                                        '<tpl for=".">',
                                            '<div>',
                                               '<a href="#">',
                                                   '<img id="{name}" src="resources/images/default-avatars/{thumb}" height="72" weigh="72"/>',
                                               '</a>',
                                            '</div>',
                                        '</tpl>',
                                         ]                                     
                                }, 
                               {
                                  xtype: 'filefield',  //this does not show in panel
                                  id: 'form-file',
                                  emptyText: 'Select an image',
                                  fieldLabel: 'Photo',
                                  name: 'photo-path',
                                  buttonText: '',
                                  buttonConfig: {
                                  iconCls: 'upload-icon'
                                }
    }
```

Comment: Probably unrelated to your issue, but there are so many problems with the code there. Where did you get it?

Comment: Hi Eric! I have tried to put the code together in a panel using the dataview in the extjs kitchen sink example. Could you explain further? Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is you are using

```js
layout: 'fit'
```

which will show one item in the container.
ref: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Fit

> If the container has multiple items, all of the items will all be equally sized. This is usually not desired, so to avoid this, place only a single item in the container. This sizing of all items can be used to provide a background image that is "behind" another item such as a dataview if you also absolutely position the items.

Switch the layout to any other layout and it will work.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hxscf26h/